# Attempting Catapult game, after new XNA download.The type or namespace name 'GestureType' could not be found

Tags: c#, xna, reference, windows-phone-7

I just recently downloaded the new version of XNA, and trying to follow a tutorial (that I thought was updated with the new version) I am getting a few errors

```
The type or namespace name 'GestureType' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch.TouchPanel' does not contain a definition for 'EnabledGestures'
```

I was just wondering what reference to I have to add to get this to work? Thanks!

the new download was from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=04704acf-a63a-4f97-952c-8b51b34b00ce&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the project was trying to reference the old version.  After creating a new project and moving my old code over, it is working well.

Answer (score 0):

According to the latest [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.touch.gesturetype.aspx) is now in:

> **Namespace**: Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch
>   **Assembly:** Microsoft.Xna.Framework (in microsoft.xna.framework.dll)

Comment: interesting,  well I have  Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch namespace and I have the reference to the Xna.Framework, but my gesture still isn't found :(

Comment: @Spooks: Maybe you have a reference to the assembly of the old version of XNA?

Comment: @Spooks: Don't forget to add a 'using' statement for it.

Comment: @Steve - good point, but I got a virtual earful from someone for explaining the obvious in another answer.